# Should the "upgrading Nintendo Switch microSD storage" question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing, specific-question, reopen

This is about the currently closed question: [What should I look for when upgrading Nintendo Switch microSD storage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/399355/4797) It had been [left closed in the reopen review queue.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/320155)

I don't think the above question is an off-topic recommendation question. The question is unlike the bad, off-topic examples mentioned in the Stack Overflow blog post, [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) It is more like the on-topic, good example mentioned in that blog post:

> [...] **However**, there *is* a way to ask these questions that avoids the inherent problems with shopping recommendations. For example, let’s say you wanted — as I did — to buy a point-and-shoot camera that takes good low light photos. So we’re going to ask on [photo.stackexchange.com](http://photo.stackexchange.com/), naturally!
>
> Here’s one way to ask:
>
> > **Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?**
> >
> > A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
>
> Here’s [another way](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/what-point-and-shoots-are-good-in-low-light-conditions) to ask:
>
> > **Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?**
> >
> > A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
> >
> > - a fast lens (2.0 at least)
> > - reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but preferably 800)
> > - the biggest sensor available
> >
> > The sum of these factors are really critical for low light situations.
>
> The former question provides the path of least resistance: a laundry list of products I can buy without thinking about it too much. But that answer will only be valid for a year at best. The latter question may take some thinking, but its answer will be valid *forever* … or at least until camera technology somehow shifts beyond lenses and sensors as we know them today. Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us *what you need to learn* to tell what you should buy.
>
> If I had to summarize our network in a single word, **that word is “learning”**. People come to our sites to *learn* about topics they are passionate about. As the old Chinese proverb goes, “Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.” Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning — yes, even the shopping ones.

The question is *not* asking *which* microSD card brand/model one should buy (unlike the off-topic examples mentioned in the blog post), but rather, like the on-topic example — what features/specs should one look for (or: what factors should one consider) in a microSD card?

Comment: The question has now been reopened by the reopen queue independently of this post.